# How to query a record using single date?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Example: Record A has start date field (`12/11/2013`) and end date field (`14/11/2014`). How to get record A if I query using a single date (`13/11/2014`) query as given.

```
Record  Start_date    End_date

A        12/11/2014  14/11/2014
```

This is for booking facilities system. If a user books a notebook from 12 till `14/11/2014`, other users should not be able to book the same notebook on either 12th, 13th or 14th. Using the select statement with the single date, example `13/11/2014`, how can we show to the user that the notebook has been booked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where '2014-11-13' between start_date and end_date
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5715/1)

Comment: Juergen, the query you give only can use if the dates are in the same column or field.Mine is different, start date and end date is 2 different column.

Comment: @ash Yeah, you might want to fix that

Comment: @ash: I don't get it. `start_date` and `end_date` are 2 columns, not 1.

Comment: Yeap @juergend, I have created a start date field and end date field. so, if I query using your statement it will show empty record because it is not in the same column

Comment: Now I think you don't understand. What data type do these columns have? Change them to date if they are not.

Comment: I edit back my question. It is not about the data type. 3 fields, Record, start date and end date. If user want to search between those 2 field date. If start date and end date fall in the same field, so yeah, I can use between but this is different case

Comment: @ash : The query above is correct that's why I wondering why you insist that his answer is not accurate.

Comment: @ash: I think it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5715/1. But maybe I am missing something

Comment: @juergend yeah thanks for guiding me. I am sorry if I make a mistake because I keep on trying the same query but still cant retrieve the data.Sorry again and I will accept the answer. Thank

Comment: I saw my where my mistake is and I feel really embarrass right now.Hahahaha..Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

After seeing Juergen d's answer I felt the query was right but after reading the para below the table I felt he needs something like this

```
Select case when '2014-11-13' between start_date and end_date then 'Booked' else 'Open' end case from your_table
```

Comment: I am looking for table reference. :)

Comment: Well it actually works without giving an error if you give manual dates in the place of startDate and endDate :P